# How to know where NPM is installing its binaries?

Tags: node.js, npm

After updating NPM, my binaries are not getting installed properly. The module itself is getting installed at /usr/local/lib/node_modules, but the binary is not getting installed at /usr/local/bin.

How do I know the path where the binaries are getting installed?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the `whereis` or `which` command maybe?

Comment: npm update -g // https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/updating-global-packages

Comment: @NoobCoder Fare point. `which autoprefixer` (which is the package I'm trying to install) returns a not found, so I guess that the problem is bigger than it being installed elsewhere. Thanks anyway!