# How do I check where npm is installing packages?

Tags: npm

So this runs correctly:

```
npm install -g topojson
```

But then:

```
topojson
-bash: topojson: command not found
```

How do I know where it's put topojson? [Duplicate of this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547441/how-to-know-where-npm-is-installing-its-binaries).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

and see if it tells you where it's installed.

Comment: Thanks - it says `/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.3.0/lib`, but what do I need to add to my path to get `topojson` running as a standalone command? The `lib` directory contains `node_modules` and then packages in subdirectories, but where are the actual binaries?

Comment: Do whatever procedure your OS requires for modifying the PATH environment. Windows, MacOS and Linux all have different procedures for modifying the path. Google for the answer and you will find excellent information on modifying the PATH variable for your OS.

Comment: Sorry - I know how to edit the PATH but I don't actually know what the path should be...

Comment: It tells you: Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.3.0/lib I would think.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I don't see how it could, because the contents of the `lib` directory are `dtrace/` and `node_nodules/`, not the actual packages. So confused!

Comment: Then I don't know either. That command should have shown you where the files were installed and that should have been what was used in your path. Sorry, but I have no other ideas.